# Angularjs : get the index of selected object in select tag

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the index of the selected item of my `<select>` like this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_Mois" name="mois"
        ng-model="vm.currentMois"
        ng-options="mois as mois.libelle for mois in vm.allMoisForAnnee track by mois.id"
        ng-change= "vm.moisChanged(vm.currentMois)">
</select>

vm.moisChanged = function(mois){
    var i = vm.allMoisForAnnee.indexOf(mois);
}
```

But I am always getting -1. I don't understand why.
If someone can help me on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
vm.moisChanged = function(mois){
    var i = vm.allMoisForAnnee.map(function(obj, index) {
        if(obj.libelle == mois.libelle) {
            return index;
        }
    }).filter(isFinite);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's returning -1 since the object you pass is not found in the array, Check what is actually being passed to the controller function.

Make sure  `vm.currentMois` has some object

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/05enjj8c/)**

Comment: vm.currentMois has an object which is actually the object that is selected in the <select> since ng model is bound to this tag.

Answer (score 0):

First you do not need to pass the value to your ng-change function as the model is already connected to view & controller, you can access it via 'vm.currentMois' inside you function implementation inside controller.

What you try to do inside that function is incorrect. 
The [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

if you want to find the index of the selected item you can simply have loop and find.

```
vm.moisChanged = function(mois){
      var i;
      angular.forEach(vm.allMoisForAnnee, function(item){
        if(mois.id==item.id){
          i = item;
          console.log(i);
          return false;
        }
      })
    }
```